# Typescript: typing variable with one or the other interface

Tags: typescript

I have been struggling with this, looked at StackOverflow but cannot figure out how to make this work.

I want to type `response` from an API that could return one interface if successful or a different one if on error.

I am using `redux-saga`

Here is the code:

```
export interface IAuthSuccessResponse {
  token: string;
  email: string;
}

export interface IAuthErrorResponse {
  error: string;
}

type IAuthResponse = IAuthErrorResponse | IAuthSuccessResponse;
```

and inside the `saga`:

```
    const response: IAuthResponse = yield call(Api.authenticate, tmpToken);
    const { error } = response // TS2339: property error doesnt exist on type IAuthResponse;

    if (error) {
      yield put(authenticateFailure(error));
    } else {
      const { token, email } = response // TS2339: property token/email doesnt exist on type IAuthResponse;
```

I get this error: `TS2339: property error doesn't exist on type IAuthResponse`

I wanted to avoid making all properties optional.

What would the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a type guard to narrow the type. For instance, you could do:

```
if ("error" in response) {
    yield put(authenticateFailure(response.error));
} else {
    const {token, email} = response;
}
```

More information about type guards is available in the TypeScript Handbook in the section [Type Guards and Differentiating Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).